# SSRS: How to make a list of charts that are in rows of 2x2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a list which takes each Value from a table and makes a line graph from the data based on the number of IDs supplied.SO 4 IDs with 100 Values gets me 4 charts with 100 values for the line. I have worked with SSRS tools and know that If I Just keep them in a list with a row group the chart will put them one below the other. How do I make it so the charts are on the corners of each other

For Example

I want this:

```
Chart 1       Chart 2
Chart 3       Chart 4
```

Restarting at chart 5.

But with only row groups and a list I get:

```
Chart 1
Chart 2
Chart 3
Chart 4
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2015/02/ssrs-wrapline-break-row-and-column.html  Go through this link and add group for the list as  shown in example then ad your chart to list.

Comment: Thank this is helpful